# How to serve static index with Apache and mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

So I'm using Apache and mod_wsgi to serve a django webapp. My client is a single-page application, which talks to the django back-end. Since the actual index is a static html file, I would like it so that when my user navigates to '/', then Apache serves them my static index.html, but when they visit '/foo/' or '/bar/', then they get dynamic content from the django backend.

Relevant apache conf:

```
Alias /static /path/to/static

<Directory /path/to/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /path/to/django/site>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess sitename python-home=/path/to/env python-path=/path/to/django
WSGIProcessGroup sitename
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/sitename/wsgi.py
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

However, if I try to `Alias / /path/to/static/` then django doesn't get to do its thing, since it clashes with `WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/sitename/wsgi.py`. Is there any way to make Apache serve a static file in what would otherwise be django's namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^/(foo|bar)/ /path/to/sitename/wsgi.py/$1/
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

The second directive is just to make sure it doesn't create separate instances of the application for each matched prefix. It shouldn't, but this just makes sure and is generally a good idea to use that directive anyway for various reasons.

Comment: Hi Graham, I have a similiar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55059928/configuring-wsgi-to-service-a-single-index-html-file-for-a-single-page-applicati -- is this possible?