# Configuring WSGI to service a single index.html file for a single page application

Tags: ember.js, mod-wsgi, wsgi, django-wsgi

I have a standard Django application set up using WSGI on Apache2 (Ubuntu 18.04)

I now want to serve all front end content via a single index.html file (still allowing access the /admin url and ensuring the REST api calls via /api work). I'm using Ember for the single page application.

Any help much appreciated!

Here is my current .conf set up:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/examplesite.co.uk/public_html

Alias /static /home/someuser/djangoprojects/someuser_v1_project/static
<Directory /home/someuser/djangoprojects/someuser_v1_project/static>
      Require all granted
</Directory>

Alias /media /home/someuser/djangoprojects/someuser_v1_project/media
<Directory /home/someuser/djangoprojects/someuser_v1_project/media>
      Require all granted
 </Directory>

 <Directory /home/someuser/djangoprojects/someuser_v1_project/someuser_v1_project>
 <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
 </Files>
 </Directory>

 WSGIDaemonProcess examplesite.co.uk python-home=/home/someuser/virtualenvs/someuser_env python-path=/home/someuser/djangoprojects/someuser_v1_project
 WSGIProcessGroup examplesite.co.uk
 WSGIScriptAlias / /home/someuser/djangoprojects/someuser_v1_project/someuser_v1_project/wsgi.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your index.html will be static it just needs to be sent to the user-agent (browser) as is. It doesn't need any server-side processing (WSGI).

The web-server can simply send index.html (and any js/css resources) as requested by the browser. It doesn't even need to be in the same directory as your API back-end.

I am using a set-up like this in a production app. This keeps development and deployment independent for front/back.

```
/www
  /myapp                <-- ember SPA (where normal users will go)
     index.html
    /assets
    /fonts
  /myapp_backend
    /api/v1/...          <-- backend API (API that ember talks to)
    /admin/              <-- admin section
```

You can define the backend API location in ember config production settings. (Could be different settings in development). You can then set the namespace in your ember application data adapter to this path.

```
// config/environment.js
...
APP: {
  ENV: {
         REST_API_ENDPOINT: 'myapp_backend/api/v1',
         REST_API_HOST:     'http://production-host',
       ...
       }

  ...
}

// app/adapters/application.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
import ENV from '../config/environment';
...

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: ENV.APP.REST_API_ENDPOINT,
    host:      ENV.APP.REST_API_HOST,
    ...
})
```

When a release is ready you can `ember build --environment=production` and copy 'dist' directory to the server myapp directory.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I've done PHP apps in the past with a set up like this but (I don't believe) this will work with Django since none of the code sits in the public (www in your example) directory. I was struggling with a way of being able to serve the Django code with WSGI (a must obviously), and being able to serve a static (Ember) index.html file and redirect all traffic to that. For me, the solution I've referred to below  github.com/metakermit/django-spa looks like it's going to be the best solution?

Comment: If you can set up your django API to respond to (authorized?) requests from a browser then you should be able to make your ember app make the same requests once it is loaded in your browser.

Comment: You only want to redirect requests for your base url (mysite.com) to index.html (ember app), other requests should be served by the api (or your admin code). I took a quick look at django-spa and it seems to address your use-case

Comment: Hi - that was the problem - being able to serve a static HTML and the Django code using WSGI. I thought about separate domains and then came across the plugin I've referred to which means I don't need to worry about WSGI, it's all done in the middleware. Not sure if it's the best solution but seems to work ok - not tested in production yet.

Answer (score -1):

You are much better off not using WSGI/ngnix to serve the static assets of a totally decoupled frontend app and using a service like [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com) or host the assets on AWS using ember-cli-deploy http://ember-cli-deploy.com.

Why?

- It's faster
- You can more easily automate the deployments to either app
- You don't have to think about this question
- Netlify, in particular offers things like deploy previews that make your life a joy.

If you want a specific answer, I'd check this out: https://pypi.org/project/wsgi-static-middleware/

Comment: Hi - thanks for getting back. Initially at least I would like to serve the application from the same server using WSGI. I have seen a couple of posts which discuss this (but as I say I could not get to work) so would like to pursue that first - hopefully it's possible without using middleware?

Comment: Hi, will have a look at Netlify, and have also considered just hosting my Django code, and the Ember dist folder on the same server but under different domain names. The Ember code would obviously sit on the "actual" domain. That sounds fine but the xml site map is generated in Django - on a different domain! Would that also be an issue with services such as Netlify?

Comment: I'm just serving a static index.html file now from a Django app I've created for this purpose. Haven't tested in production but don't see why this won't work and it's really simple. There's also this plugin which looks interesting https://github.com/metakermit/django-spa